# Sitecore website is not getting loaded after app pool recycle and iis reset

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, multisite

Website is hosted in multi-site environment. Earlier all sites were working fine but after app pool recycle and iis-reset none of the site is working. I checked log also but having following message but not able to find out any solution:

```
120164 20:52:38 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

132536 20:54:39 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

127708 20:56:39 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

132608 20:58:39 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

123380 21:00:00 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

79296 21:00:39 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

87196 21:02:40 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

132624 21:03:41 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

114660 21:04:40 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

128788 21:06:40 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized

131424 21:08:40 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
```

Comment: Do you see any error in browser? Or it is just infinite loading with blank screen?

Answer (score 0):

The "HttpModule is being initialized" is reported  when a new Http module is created.

There is a pool of Http Modules when the web application starts. When all modules from the pool are busy by handling current requests, new one is created and it is reported in the log by the mentioned entry. A lot of such entries sequentially reported in the log indicates heavy load of your solution. Sitecore does not create requests on his own so they should be loaded by external requests.

I would suggest that you optimize performance to make sitecore handle http requests faster 
Please check next article:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Sitecore%20Performance/Optimizing%20Sitecore%206%20and%20later.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"HttpModule is being initialized" is not an error, it is info message that indicates that site is not able to handle new requests and that is why it starts new HttpModule. If you see these messages in log of running site then it means that you should optimize site performance.

But, as it is first start of website and site doesn't start at all then I think that problem is not in general performance. It looks like something extremely heavy and long-running is performed on site start. Check your *initialize* pipeline on any customizations and try to define what could cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to the provided answers, it may indicate that Sitecore started processing session end events.
In the process of doing this, it will create an HTTP object per session entry with the URL '\session end' thus "HttpModule is being initialized" records in logs.